# VS 2015 Community Edition - Test explorer window is blank

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, test-explorer

**Edit:**

Today the problem was solved with the following VS 2015 Update: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx

---

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio 2015 Community. The test explorer window is empty, no tests are showing up, only the buttons for grouping and parallel execution are there.

I'm using NUnit, but also tried the build in MSTest Framework. The NUnit Test Adapter is installed and all tests are discovered and executed.

I've tried the following things to solve the problem, but nothing has worked so far:

- Restarting Visual Studio
- Uninstalling/Reinstalling the Test Adapter
- Reset Visual Studio settings (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083302/2568036, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17613525/2568036)
- Reset window layout
- Repair Visual Studio installation

[image: Empty test explorer window on Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition]

Comment: Hello, I had the same problem, corrected it by repairing VS

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately it also didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved with the following VS 2015 Update: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx

**Issue 9**
Authored the resource DLL. Now customers can load the TestExplorer Window with localized strings.

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you installing the framework from the Nuget packages - project right click -> Manage Nuget Packages -> type in the search bar NUnit, install it than Nunit adapter. Just in case you are downloading it from the web not from VS
2. Friend of mine had similar problem but with MS Test - repair install did not fix it but uninstall than clean install did it.